# Is there a way to spawn zombies at certain coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For my adventure map, I need to know if you can spawn zombies at certain coordinates using command blocks. Allowing them to spawn naturally in the dark is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the summon command.

`/summon [mob] [x] [y] [z]`

For example:

`/summon Zombie 32 56 21` will spawn a zombie at XYZ 32, 56, 21